# Manual removal of Nvidia driver fails due to init and busybox

Tags: nvidia, busybox, sysvinit, slackware

I'm using PorteuX (Slackware based) and in the shutdown/reboot process I want to unmount everything, which works fine unless I boot with Nvidia drivers. In this case, just before `reboot -f` step if I run `lsof /dev/nvidia*` it says both `init` and `busybox` are using `nvidia-modeset` process, which prevents me from being able to kill any Nvidia process.

I also tried to boot into `init 3` and kill all Nvidia processes, but it says the device is busy, although is not clear why.

Is there a way to force the Nvidia driver to unload without rebooting? I don't mind losing video, as this will happen in the last step before shutdown.